# How to calculate this complex integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{q+i}e^{-(q+b)^2}\text{d}q$? (Please Help)

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-integration

I want to carry out the following integration

$$\int_0^\infty  \frac{1}{q+i}e^{-(q+b)^2}\text{d}q$$

which is trivial if calculated numerically with any value for b. But I really need to get an analytic expression for this integral. I would really appreciate it if you can help with this integral. Or if you can tell it's not possible to carry it out analytically, that is also helpful.

Thanks in advance

Huijie

Comment: The Mathematica code $$Integrate[Exp[-c*q^2]/(1 + I), \{q, 0, Infinity\}] $$ outputs $$ConditionalExpression[(1/4-I*(1/4))*Sqrt[[Pi]]/Sqrt[c], Re[c] > 0]
 .$$ Maple analitically finds it only for concrete values of $c$.

Comment: Thanks experimentX, for your prompt reply. I agree with your result for b=0. But I need a more general result for any $b\in Reals$.

Comment: Thanks user64494 for your help. I have made a mistake in my title and have corrected it now. Do you have any idea about this integral?

Comment: The Mathematica command $$ Integrate[Exp[-c*(q + b)^2]/(1 + I), \{q, 0, Infinity\}] $$ produces $$(1/4-I*(1/4))*Sqrt[[Pi]]*Erfc[b*Sqrt[c]]/Sqrt[c].$$ under some conditions on $c$ and $b$.

Comment: @user64494 you are doing it wrong ... there is q in denominator too ... sadly Mathematica and Maple won't return any expression :(( also it appears that it cannot be expressed in elementary terms :((

Comment: I hope the questioner did the last edition in the question.

Comment: @user64494 no ... it was there from the beginning, on the main question. lastly my last hope matlab didn't return anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for all your effort to help, user64494 and experimentX. I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{res}\left(\frac{\left(\sqrt{\pi } e^{\frac{1}{4} z (4 b+z)} \text{erfc}\left(b+\frac{z}{2}\right)\right) \left(e^{-i z} (-2 \text{Ci}(z)-2 i \text{Si}(z)-2 \log (-z)+2 \log (z)-i \pi )\right)}{}\{z,\alpha \}\right)$$ sorry my latex do not work find

Comment: could you explain how did you get it?

Comment: That looks fantastic. Can you tell me what is $\alpha$ and give me some clue as to how you obtain this?

Comment: hi Huijie  α is a residue of the function but I think must be 0 or negative number it very difficult resolve lucky with the searching

Comment: Thanks,Capea. Could you explain your answer a bit more? It a residue of which function at which point? I would really appreciate if you could tell me how you get this result.